# Android - recyclerView return several times the same items

Tags: java, android, firebase, loops, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to get firebase data, but the problem is that it returns the same data several times.

```
imageRef = database.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(userid);
imageRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


            for (DataSnapshot mData : dataSnapshot.child("images").getChildren()) {

                for (DataSnapshot mDataTwo: dataSnapshot.child("locations").getChildren()) {

                    ItemData itemData = new ItemData();

                    String mImages = mData.getValue(String.class);
                    String mLocations = mDataTwo.getValue(String.class);

                    itemData.setImages(mImages);
                    itemData.setLocations(mLocations);

                    data.add(itemData);

                }

            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
```

UPDATE:

This is my database structure.

```
"Users" : {

"X7aVfZH5oZbIaeyLm9FAjOSr5Gd2" : {
  "images" : {
    "urlImages1" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/anthiefy.appspot.com/o/X7aVfZH5oZbIaeyLm9FAjOSr5Gd2%2FImages%2FImg1.jpg?alt=media&token=e26fd6a2-2be7-4a01-920e-0aed1fe06436",
    "urlImages2" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/anthiefy.appspot.com/o/X7aVfZH5oZbIaeyLm9FAjOSr5Gd2%2FImages%2FImg2.jpg?alt=media&token=40165918-3b46-4b22-b0ef-255965b7855d",
    "urlImages3" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/anthiefy.appspot.com/o/X7aVfZH5oZbIaeyLm9FAjOSr5Gd2%2FImages%2FImg3.jpg?alt=media&token=cfd7d00d-9b1a-44fd-80d4-a2947f7de743",
    "urlImages4" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/anthiefy.appspot.com/o/X7aVfZH5oZbIaeyLm9FAjOSr5Gd2%2FImages%2FImg4.jpg?alt=media&token=995419a7-70f7-4330-b046-d06a4d54453e",
    "urlImages6" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/anthiefy.appspot.com/o/X7aVfZH5oZbIaeyLm9FAjOSr5Gd2%2FImages%2FImg6.jpg?alt=media&token=ee6f566a-a9e5-4e8f-9d53-64d3f3bc97a6",
    "urlImages7" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/anthiefy.appspot.com/o/X7aVfZH5oZbIaeyLm9FAjOSr5Gd2%2FImages%2FImg7.jpg?alt=media&token=883a3321-fbba-49bd-aae3-14b005b4cc5b"
  },
  "locations" : {
    "locations1" : "14.2830817 -89.7263953",
    "locations2" : "14.2661424 -89.7220017",
    "locations3" : "14.2846352 -89.7251991",
    "locations4" : "14.2684987 -89.7266704",
    "locations5" : "14.2684987 -89.7266704",
    "locations6" : "14.2684987 -89.7266704",
    "locations7" : "14.2684987 -89.7266704"
  }
```

I have tried many ways, I have also sought the solution but without any fortune. If someone can help me, very grateful.

Comment: Your code doesn't look right. Why are you double looping?

Comment: post your firebase database structure.

Comment: try to remove one loop then try it,

Comment: Please, check the update.

Comment: try putting data.add(itemData); in the outside for loop

Comment: Do you want to get all the locations per image?

Comment: yes, that is what I want

Comment: Are there supposed to be all 7 images per location, or one image per location?

Comment: one image per location.

Comment: what does getChildren() return, is it a list?

Comment: So your code is bad, and your database structure is bad. Your code is double looping, so it is getting 7 locations for each image. But rather than fixing that, you should be redesigning your database, so that all relevant data is returned in single row.

Comment: A better structure can be organize them by independent object. instead of having image here and location there. Better to have each object has image and location

Comment: @Dr4ketheb4dass Tell me how I can organize and retrieve them to show them the images in an imageview and the location in a texview?

Comment: "Users" : {

"X7aVfZH5oZbIaeyLm9FAjOSr5Gd2" : { "image": "linkToImage", "location" : "13.7474 -41.3737" }

Comment: You can have as many object as you want, but make sure each have image and location.

Comment: you need to clear the data object

Comment: thanks everyone for answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is for every single Image you are iterating every location and creating object of that Item.

```
    List<String> images=new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> locations=new ArrayList<>();
    for (DataSnapshot mData : dataSnapshot.child("images").getChildren()) {
        String image = mData.getValue(String.class);
        images.add(image);


    }
    for (DataSnapshot mDataTwo: dataSnapshot.child("locations").getChildren()) {
        String location = mDataTwo.getValue(String.class);
        locations.add(location);
    }
    if (images.size()==locations.size()){
        for (int i=0;i<locations.size();i++){
            String image=images.get(i);
            String location=locations.get(i);
            ItemData itemData = new ItemData();
            itemData.setImages(image);
            itemData.setLocations(location);
            data.add(itemData);
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Try out this code. It'll help you.

Comment: A very good solution. I just added "data.removeAll (data);" at first.

Comment: @Juy yeah its right indeed but i wrote the code that map one image with one location and your code seems execute-one images with seven location, if you use **data.removeAll(data);** than for all location you will get same image. And your code time complexity is BigO(n^2) and what i wrote is BigO(n) time complexity.

Answer (score 1):

you need to clear the data object before it control goes into the loop.
what happening in your app is when anything changes on firebase database it gives all the present data to mobile so everytime you change anything on the cloud the redundant data also comes into the DataSnapShot object so you need to clear the ArrayList or list that you've taken as 'data'.